# Client/Server Programming, Cannot convert System.net.IPAddress to String

Tags: c#

Im developing a client server program. On the client side i developed a program that sends data and receives data.

I managed to parse a static ip address but i tried using IPAddress.Any but it returns that error. (Cannot convert System.net.IPAddress to String).

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace client
{
    class HMSClient
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                //---Connect to a port
                Console.Write("Input port" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                int PORT_NO = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Input a Command" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                while (true)
                {
                    //---data to send to the server---
                    string commands = Console.ReadLine();

                    //---create a TCPClient object at the IP and port no.---
                    //IPAddress SERVER_IP = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];

                    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IPAddress.Any, PORT_NO);

                    NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
                    byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(commands);

                    //---send the command---
                    Console.WriteLine("Command: " + commands);
                    nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

                    //---read back the response
                    byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    Console.WriteLine("Response: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client cannot find target to send the command" + Environment.NewLine + e);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you recreate the client and reconnect each iteration again and again?

Comment: I mean i could move them out the loop, but yeah that should of been done a while ago.

Comment: it would probably less resource demanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`TcpClient Constructor (String, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/115ytk56(v=vs.110).aspx) you're using is defined as following:

```
public TcpClient(
    string hostname,
    int port
)
```

So as 1st argument a `String` is needed and C# can't convert a `IPAddress` implicitly to a `String`. So you need to use [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your `IPAddress`.

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IPAddress.Any.ToString(), PORT_NO);
```

---

**Hint:** Remember `IPAddress.Any` representates the String `0.0.0.0`, which isn't a valid `IPAddress` to connect to with a `TcpClient`

Comment: Aha! i added tostring before without the () which gave me the error. Its the reason why i got confused, thanks!

Comment: i get this error  IPv4 address 0.0.0.0 and IPv6 address ::0 are unspecified addresses that cannot be used as a target address. Do you have any idea whats happening? i feel like its a conflict of some sort.

Comment: yes a TcpClient needs a valid IPAdress to connect to an `0.0.0.0` isn't a vaild IPAddress. You need to enter a valid target IPAdress there.

Comment: @Freon you could also connect to the server using the hostname

Answer (score 1):

TcpClient constructor takes a string as a first argument not an IpAddress object.

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IpAddress.Any.ToString(), PORT_NO);
```

or as IpAddress.Any is actually "0.0.0.0"

```
 TcpClient client = new TcpClient("0.0.0.0", PORT_NO);
```

Answer (score 0):

You coud use .ToString after .Any and it will be converted to string, as you need in the TcpClient constructor